# How do I pass an object (created by a buttonClick event) from child to parent in react when already using props for a styled button

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, parent-child, react-props

I've hard coded the value and id for each button, and I'm capturing those during an onClick event and returning an object with the data: {fretNumber: event.target.value, stringNumber: event.target.id} I want to pass this information to the parent (App) and back down to another child. I'm having trouble because I'm already passing props into the child app for the styled component buttons. Maybe it doesn't matter? I'm new to this and have been stuck for days. Thanks for any help you can give!

Child Component (Fretboard)

```
import BassFretboard from '../BassFretboard.png';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Button = styled.button`
  top: ${(props) => props.top};
  left: ${(props) => props.left};
  etc.
`;

function Fretboard(props) {
  function buttonClicked(event) {
    return ( {
      fretNumber: event.target.value,
      stringNumber: event.target.id,
  });
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <img
        src={BassFretboard}
      />
      <Button
        top="60%"
        left="0.8%"
        width="4%"
        padding="1%"
        value="1"
        id="0"
        onClick={buttonClicked}
      >
        E/0
      </Button>
```

(the other 79 buttons not shown)

Parent Component (App)

```
import Fretboard from './Fretboard';

function App(props) {

  return (
        <Fretboard />
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to accomplish.

To get this information into the parent component, the parent has to pass down a handler as a prop. For example,

```
function App() {
  function onClickFret(data) { /* implementation */ }
  
  return <FretBoard onClickFret={onClickFret} />
}
```

In `FretBoard`, this function will be exposed on the `props` object and can be used in your `buttonClicked` handler. This might look like

```
function buttonClicked(event) {
  props.onClickFret({ 
    fretNumber: event.target.value,
    stringNumber: event.target.id,
  })
}
```

`data` in `onClickFret` in `App` will be the object you are calling `props.onClickFret` with.

To then pass it back down to another child of `App`, the value has to be stored in state in `App`, and propagated down via props to the other child.

You might implement `onClickFret` in `App` like

```
function App() {
  const [selectedFret, setSelectedFret] = useState(undefined)
  function onClickFret(data) { 
    setSelectedFret(data) 
  }
  
  return <FretBoard onClickFret={onClickFret} />
}
```

`selectedFret` can then be used as a prop to pass this data back down to another child component.

Generally, this pattern is called "[lifting up state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)", or "[events up, props down](https://jasonformat.com/props-down-events-up/)"

Comment: Thanks so much Tyler! I was making it harder than it was...